# Blogging application for Django

Tags: python, django, blogs, knowledge-management

I have a website that I developed in Django

After the fact I want to add a blog, I don't feel inclined to writing a blogging application from scratch.

Can you recommend a very light weight blogging application, nothing fancy. Just the most vanilla django blogging application I could add to this project.

Comment: I thought Mezzanine (http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) was pretty good.

Comment: This looks like a littler overkill, I just want something to add to the existing site. www.knoxfer.com/blog

Comment: fyi - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it. Usually not considered best practice to link to your sites in SO questions.

Comment: My question is: Why do you want something as heavy as `django` handling a static site? I'd think a static site generator would do. (My fav is [pelican](http://blog.getpelican.com/))

Comment: Miki, wasn't aware of that rule, will edit the post.

Comment: I can recommend the Stack Overflow tour that was presented to you upon your registration here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer django-simple-blogs no frills blogging app.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-simple-blog/0.1.0

Doesn't have a template though - just a few tags to help you. You'd need to make your own templates